# Modernizr javascript code explanation

Tags: javascript, html, modernizr

I'm working on some HTML5 template and I'm watching some examples on the internet how other guys done it , since I would like to put my work on Theme Forest , I found this peace of code in one of examples and I really cant get it how it works . So please if anyone could help me to understand this it would be great

```
var pd = {},
verboseBuild = !0,
screenXs = 480,
ltIE9 = !1;

/* Modernizer */

!$("html").is(".lt-ie9") || (ltIE9 = !0),

Modernizr.addTest("ipad", function () {
    return !!navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i);
}),
Modernizr.addTest("iphone", function () {
    return !!navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i);
}),
Modernizr.addTest("ipod", function () {
    return !!navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i);
}),
Modernizr.addTest("appleios", function () {
    return Modernizr.ipad || Modernizr.ipod || Modernizr.iphone;
}),
Modernizr.appleios && $("html").addClass("ios-device"),
    !verboseBuild || console.log("Starting builds:"),
    $(document).ready(function () {
        !verboseBuild || console.log("-- starting proton.common build"), 
        pd.common.build();
    }),
```

and can anyone explain what verbosebuild = !0 mean and itE9 = !1 too?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Well:

- `!0` is just an alias for `true`
- `!1` is just an alias for `false`
- `!!<something>` in simple words, casts `<something>` to boolean (will always return `true` or `false`)

(Btw, I don't know the reasons why their developers did the first 2, In my opinion, that would be microoptimization, that shouldn't be done).

So, for example:

`ltIE9 = !1` means IE version is 9 or higher

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Just curious, how is `!1` a microoptimization? Doesn't JS have to evaluate `1` to `true` first? I would've that that `false` would've been faster than `!1`

Comment: I'm not sure if it is, but I couldn't think of other reason they did it. Why do you think they did it?

Comment: Misguided ego, is my opinion. Seasoned developers will know the developer who wrote this is just blowing hot air, novice developers will be "impressed" (unfortunately) by the abstract and unusual syntax and think that the developer that wrote this must know something that they don't. Ultimately, `!0` and `!1` is absolutely nonsense.